# Don't know what's happening with the Smoke Effector (probably simple fix)

Tags: smoke-simulation

Probably and hopefully a simple answer; my smoke effector is just showing a block of smoke, instead of a sort of explosion which I'm making. It was working fine yesterday, but I must've messed with something. Thanks in advance.[image]

(my screenshots aren't working for some reason so I had to take the photo with my phone. Sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: can you show the properties set to the object working as inflow?

Comment: SOrry, it was just me being stupid.Literally just because it was set to frame 0